# fading in a webpage after jquery intro

Tags: jquery, web

I basically created a small sequence with jquery, a logo changing colors, and then I it to fade out and the webpage to fade in. I understand how to make this work for images, I'm just having issues with how to make an entire webpage fade in. 
Maybe there's a way for it to be hiding behind the sequence so it's just naturally revealed when the sequence ends? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the entire page in a `<div>`, make sure the image is outside of the div, and use `fadeIn()`.

If you try with `<body>`, your image won't be visible.

You can use `setTimeout` as well to delay the fade out of the image:

```
$('#my_div').hide(); 
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#my_image').fadeOut(1000, function() {
       $('#my_div').fadeIn(); 
    });
}, 2000);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BGtAA/1/

Comment: I liked this one, simple and the demo really really helped. My only issue is that the body now is just appearing instead of being hidden. I'm sure it's just a silly mistake on my part. I'm new to stackoverflow, is there a way to show my code that I'm working with?

Comment: YAY! I got it guys, thanks. My issue with before was I needed to explicitly state diplay:none in the div tag. @Wesley Murch your solution worked like a charm, here's my result: 

www.erindepew.com 

the site's still in the testing/de-bugging phase, but you can see the intro at least! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

What if you got the page height and then create a div that is white and over your content. When the DOM is ready then you fade that div out.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the content in a `div` which is initially hidden.  Once your animation is done, fade it out and in the callback of that `fadeOut`, fade the content `div` in:

http://jsfiddle.net/P33Xm/

Comment: Nice touch with the animation :) Why are people hiding `<body>` when obviously this will hide everything, including the loading image?